# How can I add twitter logo as icon in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I can not find the Twitter logo in the icons, there is Facebook and WhatsApp logo but not Twitter. plz, let me know how can I use Twitter/ Larry bird as an icon in my flutter project. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

use package font_awesome_flutter

https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter

```
 Icon(
      FontAwesomeIcons.twitter,
      size: 100,
    ),
```

Comment: You seem to have copied from [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75284861/4826457) along with its score...

Comment: yes, you got that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the library [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter), you can find most social media logos there as Icons
but you will find twitter icons in:

```
FontAwesomeIcons.twitter;
FontAwesomeIcons.twitterSquare;
```